# Result Set not displaying data in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am retrieving data from database in JSP in a result set. ResultSet in not empty but it is not displaying data in html tags, i.e. h3 is empty

```
ResultSet rs = null;
String sqlStr;

sqlStr = "SELECT * from IDEAS";
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlStr);

<% while (rs.next()) { %>
<h3> <% rs.getString("heading"); %></h3>
<% } %>
```

All other statements like insert , delete are working.

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't be doing that. JSP is definitely not a place to access Result Set. If you writing real code to be deployed somewhere in production, I will say this is a BIG BIG no. Read more about oops concept and segregate and modularize your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
<h3> <%= rs.getString("heading"); %></h3>
```

---

**Note:** putting java code in view is discouraged, put it in Servlet or Controller and use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) in view layer in jsp

Comment: I have used it , but for the question I wrote the code that way. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Its a not a good practice to use that code in JSP layer . You should be using a backbean where you do your coding and just retrieve data to be viewed in JSP using JSTL.